# MemoryError merging 2 datasets

Tags: database, pandas, dataframe, merge, out-of-memory

Hey guys I'm asking for a solution to a problem merging data

I have 2 dataset

```
df_311.shape 
(999999, 16)
df_bldg.shape
(855058, 12)
```

I want to merge this 2 datasets using the column ZipCode existing in both datasets.

```
df_total = pd.merge(df_311,df_bldg,how='inner',on='ZipCode')
```

and it appears this error

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 35.9 GiB for an array with shape (4824979078,) and data type int64
```

could you help me please trying to find a solution to this?

Comment: Buy a machine with more memory? But in all seriousness you need to think about this merge. It's clear you have duplicates which is why your expected output is 4B rows. Is that really what you need to do? If it can't fit in memory there's not much you can do about that, though perhaps you can try storing data in smaller types like `int8`, or `category` if it's at all close. But 4B rows will take up space regardless....